# Why are we so sure about Map results?

Tags: functional-style, core-language

I do abuse it often but when I have faced this feature first time I was really suprised:

```
i = 0;
(i++; # - i) & /@ Range[5]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

What am I asking about is **how do we know `Map` will do 'mapping' position after position?** Of course it might look logical but it is not stated, and then, since I know nothing about memory allocation etc., I could expect strange results. To be more precise, I could expect them only in cases where mapping funcion is changing during mapping.

I have failed to find a word in documentation, only related but **not important** in this case:

> Leaves are visited before roots

---

Have I missed something?

Comment: You don't know, but does it matter?

Comment: @rcollyer Yes it does. It is created so someone knows it, I would love to know it too for sure. It is not the gravitation where we are forced to stick with theories which "have been failed to be proven wrong" while we are anticipating they are only approximations.

Comment: There is a difference between the manner in which it is implemented and a guarantee by specification. I think there is nothing except compatibility constraints that forces `Map` to behave this way. However, I highly doubt that this will change as long as the evaluator remains single-threaded. One can imagine other implementations of the *Mathematica* language in which this might not apply.

Comment: I think you missed my point. At the user level, does it matter if a list implemented via a linked list or binary tree? The binary tree implementation makes searching easier, but I do not believe (I may be wrong) it affects traversal time. Or, it could have [multiple indexes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) for different work loads. Either way, it works, and is reasonably fast. So, why should we care?

Comment: @rcollyer I'm not talking about what really is happening while working but about results. Why every one of You is so sure it will behave in the same way with multi-threaded evaluator for example? I have doubts because I'm not familiar with whats inside and documentation shows no example of this kind of `Map` usage. I only know it works from experience. That is what bothers me.

Comment: There is no formal specification for the *Mathematica* language, so indeed all we have to rely on is common practice and personal experience. If WRI succeeds in formalizing the language and reimplementing it outside of *Mathematica*, things will be different since we will know with certainty whether this is considered a legitimate assumption. Until then, I would suggest that if it works, you can use it.

Comment: Without information about this an error may occur while using 'Map' this way with multi-core evaluator, caused by common variable "i". This kind of things come to my mind. @OleksandrR. Not perfect, but this is an answer. :)

Comment: Of course, I agree with you that this might be a problem. What we can be reasonably certain of is that the evaluator was never designed with concurrency in mind and that multi-threaded term rewriting is difficult to implement in general, so it's unlikely that this will change before a formal language specification appears.

Comment: @OleksandrR. likely the formalization will only include maximum complexity requirements, e.g. traversing a list should have $O(n)$ complexity, then _any_ method that achieves that, or better, is acceptable within the bounds of the language. So, if an implementer wants to include a hook for fast searches, that is acceptable as long as the required specs are met.

Comment: I reach a degree of confidence about my applications of `Map` because I test my code (always).

Comment: @Kuba `Map` is an abstraction for list traversal. Ultimately, the method used only matters in meeting complexity requirements. Getting into the details of _how_ the underlying algorithm deals with such things as multi-core breaks the abstraction. There is a lot of power in that. Take a look at the c++ standard library; it has an entire section in generic algorithms expressly for this purpose. The vast majority of the time, we don't need to know how something does its job, just that it does.

Comment: @Kuba (cont'd) Also, relying on the behavior of `Map` to traverse the list in order is a _bug_ in your code. Simply because other methods could be used, and dependence on this behavior is fragile, at best.

Comment: I think this is covered by the [Standard Evaluation Procedure](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheStandardEvaluationProcedure.html).  Exceptions in the case of parallel evaluation are covered in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ParallelTools/tutorial/ParallelEvaluation.html#217827517), too.

Comment: @rcollyer it depends on whether the specification is written to allow improved performance in another implementation or to achieve maximum compatibility with existing code. Since the traversal order can potentially be user-visible, I think there will have to be some mention of this in any formal description intended as a useful basis for a real implementation. Think of the x86 memory ordering requirements, for example. The particular ordering of memory operations isn't specified, but it must *appear* to user code that they are ordered in a certain way.

Comment: @rcollyer Kuba's point is that without a statement one way or the other specifying what `Map` actually does, it is impossible to say whether relying on this behavior is a bug or not. Since there is no formal requirement for `Map` even to exist, is it a bug to use it? I don't think so.

Comment: @OleksandrR. As there is no requirement for in-order traversal, relying on it will likely result in unexpected behavior. So, I stand by my argument that it is a bug, and Kuba got lucky. Do I have code where I've been lucky? Absolutely. But, it invites bugs in future versions which I've been bitten by.

Comment: @rcollyer so, given that the documentation is far from exhaustive and in many cases appeals to analogy or approximate "effective" behavior, what can we actually rely on? The documentation claims e.g. that "`Function` constructs can be nested in any way. Each is treated as a scoping construct, with named inner variables being renamed if necessary." Obviously, this is not true and bugs resulting from it are frequently encountered. I strongly feel that in the absence of a formal specificaiton, the observable behavior has to be the canonical arbiter of how the language is to be understood.

Comment: @OleksandrR. you are correct: in the case of ambiguity, then the observable behavior is the correct one. However, in the case of ambiguity, _expect_ the behavior to change. Additionally, the lack of documentation on some aspect (e.g. in-order traversal) should be viewed as being worse than ambiguous. It is undefined behavior, and in a formalized language, those behaviors must be used with extreme caution as there is _no guarantee_ they will behave the same from call to call. They, quite literally, could depend on the phase of the moon.

Comment: @rcollyer I think your statements are quite correct for a language with a formal and widely recognized specification, such as C. For one like *Mathematica* that is specified descriptively rather than normatively (and informally, incompletely, and sometimes incorrectly at that), one can never have absolute confidence. Moreover, there is not and never has been any guarantee whatsoever that any aspect of the language will remain stable from version to version. At best we have the established convention and Wolfram's claims that backward compatibility is important.

Comment: I would say that one can rely on this behavior, because `Map` first creates a resulting list, and only then passes it to the top-level evaluator. There are many ways to see that, here is one:`Trace@Catch[Map[Throw["Done"] &, Range[4]]]`. Now, for evaluation process, it is known that it always goes from left to right for elements at the same level in an expression. These observations taken together mean that the above behavior is robust (at least as far as I can tell).

Comment: @rcollyer In this particular case, I feel that the changes are highly unlikely, because that would require a fundamental change of how `Map` interacts with the evaluator (see my comment above) - which is very unlikely, to my mind.

Comment: I want to thank everyone who is taking part in this discussion. I have to analyse it all but I definitelly know more now. Though imo someone competent, so any one here exept me :), should gather most important quotes and post the answer/conclusion. Maybe @LeonidShifrin. Also question should be stated clearer. I think it is "a real question" and is useful for future visitors.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin you are likely correct, and I would have assumed in-order traversal as it is the simplest to implement. I was just trying to inject caution into reliance on undocumented behavior, even if it is testable behavior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm afraid my comment was too obscure to be noticed.  Further, I disagree with one premise somewhere in the commentary, and I wish to make a fuller explanation to see if I understand correctly or incorrectly.  Finally, I think the question is answered in the documentation on the [Standard Evaluation Procedure](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheStandardEvaluationProcedure.html):

> - Evaluate the head of the expression.
> - Evaluate each element in turn.
> - Apply transformations associated with the attributes Orderless, Listable, and Flat.
> - Apply any definitions that you have given.
> - Apply any built-in definitions.
> - Evaluate the result.

The first two implies that parts 0, 1, 2,... will be evaluated in order (unless one cavils that "in turn" does not imply order).

When `Map[f, {1, 2, 3}]` is evaluated, we get, after `Map`, `f`, and `{1, 2, 3}` are evaluated,

```
{f[1], f[2], f[3]}
```

Next this `List` is evaluated, with `f[1]`, `f[2]`, `f[3]` being evaluated in turn.  Thus with the OP's function, the side effect on `i` is defined.  `Trace` will show that what happens conforms to standard evaluation (of course).

Note that the mapping part (applying `f` to each element of `{1, 2, 3}`) might be done in *any order*.  What matters is that the intermediate list `{f[1], f[2], f[3]}` is then evaluated in a defined order (left-to-right).

So, I think this behavior is defined by the documentation.

---

*Edit: An additional Reference*

In the [tutorial on Evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Evaluation.html), it states in "an expression like `h[Subscript[e, 1], Subscript[e, 2]\[Ellipsis]]`, *Mathematica* evaluates "each element `Subscript[e, i]` in turn."  I think the "in turn" with the reference to the subscript `i` must mean in the natural order of 1, 2,....  There always seem to be questions of interpretation in documentation, but if writers did not mean that, I think they could be fairly criticized for misleading users, which I doubt they are.

Comment: You are correct, I don't read "in turn" as "in order." "In order" is the simplest interpretation, but not necessarily the only one. That said, even with the out-of-order execution done by processors, a dependency analysis must be performed to ensure that re-ordering is even possible. It is simpler, but not necessarily faster, if no reordering is done.

Comment: @rcollyer Yours is a more cautious interpretation, but I will probably stick to mine. :)  On the other hand, as a matter style, we might be in agreement that such side effects as in the OP's example should be avoided unless impractical.  I would probably use `MapIndexed` or perhaps `FoldList` for that kind of thing.

Comment: To each their own. :) And, yes we are in agreement that the OP's implementation is impractical and that `MapIndexed` is the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

On my installation of Mathematica 9.01 (Windows 7 x64), with the lightweight grid enabled

```
ii=0;
(#-ii++)& /@ Range[1,10]

out[1]= {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
```

and

```
ii=0;
Parallelize[(#-ii++)& /@ Range[1,10]]

out[2] = {-3, -3, -1, -1, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7, 8}
```

In fact, I get a different result each time I run the latter variant.

One of the delights of functional programing is that, in principle, pure functional programs are much easier to analyse to identify how they may safely be parallelized than are programs written in the imperative style.  Clearly, Parallelize makes some (generally reasonable) assumptions about the nature of the functional code it is being asked to execute in parallel that are violated in the above simple expression.  For that reason, I always try to keep resolutely within the functional idiom when writing Mathematica (or Wolfram Language if you must).  I found that learning Haskell (which is rigorously functional) helped me a lot with writing better Mathematica code.