# Order of Map[] evaluation

Tags: functional-style, map, side-effect

Does `f /@ list` evaluate the `f`'s in any particular order?  For example, does it evaluate `f` on each element of the list sequentially?  If `f` has side effects that affect its future evaluations, then the result can depend on the order in which the functions are evaluated.  The documentation for `ParallelMap` says "`ParallelMap` will give the same results as `Map`, except for side effects during the computation," but it doesn't seem to explain how `Map` itself handles side effects.

Comment: I knew I can't be the only one: [27593](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27593/5478)

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate because this is exactly what was my doubt when I asked that question. Let me know if you disagree.